# python play generated sound and accurate plot

Tags: python, audio, plot

I am looking for a way the accurately plot sound generated in real time, using python. 
Basically, I am generating a tone with the frequency varying following a noise function. When the frequency reaches certain thresholds, I need to output a visual cue (ie: a print statement)

I have been outputting the audio using pyaudio, which works fine. But I have yet to find a way to plot it, or monitor when it reaches certain levels.

EDIT : to clarify a little bit : Lets say I generate 1 second of samples. The frequency reaches the desired level at 0.1 second and 0.7 second. How can I play this audio sample, and print a statement precisely at the moment it reaches 0.1 second and 0.7 second. How can I sync some sort of visual clue, or any function call, precisely synced with the audio playing.

Comment: I have tried using scipy.fft() to plot it, and it works well. But what I am not sure how to do is how to plot it precisely as it gets played. So that I can print a message at accurately the moment the frequency reaches the threshold.

Answer (score 1):

FFT and, for this matter, any spectral analysis of discrete samples, will (almost) never give you a precise graph of spectra.

If you give the FFT the entire input, it will provide you with the highest resolution graph, but this graph will contain the entire input.

The less samples you provide, the lower the spectral resolution will be. It's a trade-off.

Nevertheless, finding the exact sample in which a certain frequency is introduced is quite meaningless.

You should provide the graphing a certain portion of the samples (a 'window'). It is trivial to calculate the playback time it represents. Finding the appropriate number of samples to use depends on your needs (transient vs spectral resolution).

I don't know what is your knowledge of signal processing so I do not wish to get too technical at the moment, but the general method is quite trivial:

1. Find the appropriate number of samples that suits your needs.
2. Chart/analyze those windows in parallel to the playback or ahead of it.
3. Determine the time corresponding to the identified window.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it actually solved part of my problem. I wasn't looking at this properly. However, there is another part to the problem. Since I am analyzing a chunk of samples at a time, how would I be able to precisely time something when the frequency reaches a certain level. Lets say I am analyzing 1 second of samples, I might have already reached the level I am looking for long before I analyse it. I need to be able to make a function call the very moment it reaches the desired frequency.

Comment: Playback and spectral analysis are separate processes, using the same data differently. FFT's complexity is `O(nlogn)` and the analysis of a certain window should not require more than its playback time to complete. You can probably analyze the window as it is played back and display the results at an unnoticeable delay, given the window is small enough. There are other ways of doing this, this is the most trivial one that comes to mind, provided you can tolerate a small delay. If not, it is fairly easy to avoid this delay.